# How to get a raw memory pointer to a managed class?

Tags: c#, pointers, reflection

How do I find a raw pointer to a *managed* class in C#, and, hopefully, it's raw size in memory? Obviously, this is not allowed by CLR - more precisely, strictly prohibited, as unmanaged representation of managed classes should never, ever be worked with for both stability and safe reasons - so I'm looking for a hack. I'm not looking for serializing - I do actually need a dump of managed class as it is represented in raw memory.

More precisely, I'm looking for something like function `getObjectPtr` in the following example:

```
IntPtr getObjectPtr(Object managedClass) {...}

void main() {
    var test=new TestClass();
    IntPtr* ptr_to_test=getObjectPtr(test);
    Console.WriteLine(ptr_to_test.ToString());
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I've finally found a solution by myself, and, when came back to post it as an answer, was totally surprised by the amount of so-quickly already posted answers... Thanks to all of you! This was very quick and totally unexpected.

The closest to mine solution was @thehennyy's one, but I'm not posting it since @Chino proposed far better one (sorry I've mistaken it to be wrong at first, I've just forgot to dereference the pointer again). It does not require a code to be unsafe and a bit more tolerates GC:

```
class Program
{
    // Here is the function in case anyone needs it.
    // Note, though, it does not preserve the handle while you work with
    // pointer, so it is less reliable than the code in Main():
    static IntPtr getPointerToObject(Object unmanagedObject)
    {
        GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(unmanagedObject, GCHandleType.WeakTrackResurrection);
        IntPtr thePointer = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(GCHandle.ToIntPtr(gcHandle));
        gcHandle.Free();
        return thePointer;
    }
    class TestClass
    {
        uint a = 0xDEADBEEF;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] cls = new byte[16];

        var test = new TestClass();

        GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(test, GCHandleType.WeakTrackResurrection);
        IntPtr thePointer = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(GCHandle.ToIntPtr(gcHandle));
        Marshal.Copy(thePointer, cls, 0, 16); //Dump first 16 bytes...
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(thePointer.ToInt32())));
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(cls));

        Console.ReadLine();

        gcHandle.Free();
    }
}
/* Example output (yours should be different):
40-23-CA-02
4C-38-04-01-EF-BE-AD-DE-00-00-00-80-B4-21-50-73

That field's value is "EF-BE-AD-DE", 0xDEADBEEF as it is stored in memory. Yay, we found it!
*/
```

Hovewer, now I'm a bit clueless. According to the [this](http://abhisheksur.com/2011/09/internals-of-net-objects-and-use-of-sos.html) article, first 2 addresses in the class should be pointers to SyncBlock and RTTI structure, and therefore the first field's address must be offset by 2 words [8 bytes in 32-bit systems, 16 bytes in 64-bit systems] from the beginning. Mine is 64-bit; however, as you can see in the output, it is obvious that first field's raw offset from the object's address is only 4 bytes, which doesn't make any sense.

I've asked this as a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33806758/what-are-layout-and-size-of-a-managed-classs-header-in-unmanaged-memory).
<s>Maybe I should ask this as a separate question, but it is possible that there is an error in my solution.</s>

Comment: Short disclaimer: I've found nothing by googling, as search results usually refer to something like "C++ pointers" and "Tutorials for C# unsafe  for dummies", and I've failed to find the appropriate method in C# (including looking in Marshal class) by myself. I was pretty sure this question should have been asked before, but looking on SO for "Raw C# pointer", "C# pointer to class", "Raw pointer to class memory" and "Raw pointer to managed class" yielded no results.

Comment: In general you can't do it cause in the middle of your dumping GC can move your object to other location.

Comment: Perhaps, you can use `var h = GCHandle.Alloc(obj); var address = (IntPtr)h;`.

Comment: Maybe you should open a new question with the content of your edit.

Comment: @thehennyy, thanks! I've just did it, and included a link to the new question in this one.

Comment: Nice! That means a third way of extracting the object pointer. I have never thought about using the GCHandle to read the object pointer, but now I see it is completely viable. The other two options are using `__makeref` to create a typed reference on a variable, then getting a pointer to that and extract the internal object pointer field; or using generated IL, as shown in the other answer. The second method requires using `unsafe`, and only the last one doesn't depend on any internal memory layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey is this what you want?:

```
GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(yourObject,GCHandleType.WeakTrackResurrection);
IntPtr thePointer = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(gcHandle);
```

Comment: Your answer does not even need a code to be 'unsafe' as the previously accepted one! Sorry I didn't notice it at first. When I tested your solution the first time, I thought it was wrong, but after I decided to write a comment I've ran a few more test to determine exact error and suddenly realized I simply forgot to dereference it once again:
`GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(test, GCHandleType.WeakTrackResurrection);
IntPtr thePointer = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(GCHandle.ToIntPtr(gcHandle));
Marshal.Copy(thePointer, cls, 0, 16);
WriteAsHexArray(cls);`
Thanks! It's quicker and better!

Answer (score 5):

You can write a small IL function that leaks an objects address.

```
var o = new object();

var d = new DynamicMethod("GetPtr", typeof(IntPtr), new Type[] {typeof(object)}, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule);
var il = d.GetILGenerator();
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

var address = (IntPtr)d.Invoke(null, new object[] {o});
Console.WriteLine(address);
```

The source is: [IllidanS4 / SharpUtils
/ UnsafeTools.cs](https://github.com/IllidanS4/SharpUtils/blob/a3b4da490537e361e6a5debc873c303023d83bf1/Unsafe/UnsafeTools.cs)

Comment: Thanks! It is neat, but such using of IL Emiter turned out to have some consequences. First time I've tried it I've had to enable unsafe code, as otherwise it threw that "Runtime can be put in unstable state" exception while running the delegate. I don't remember it's exact name and I cannot reproduce it, as now that code works smoothly without 'unsafe'-s and any exceptions whatsoever. Maybe it uses a compiled function stored somewhere in the cache, maybe it accept exactly this DynamicMethod to be a safe and verified... There are many options, but the fact is that this solution is unstable.

Comment: @DeFazer The method is not verifiable due to the conversion between O and *. Try using the version from my library, it should bypass the verifiability checks.