# What are layout and size of a managed class's header in unmanaged memory?

Tags: c#, reflection

Recently, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802676/how-to-get-a-raw-memory-pointer-to-a-managed-class), I've asked how to get a raw memory address of class in C# (it is a crude unreliable hack and a bad practice, don't use it unless you really need it). I've succeeded, but then a problem arose: according to [this](http://abhisheksur.com/2011/09/internals-of-net-objects-and-use-of-sos.html) article, first 2 words in the class raw memory representation should be pointers to SyncBlock and RTTI structures, and therefore the first field's address **must be offset by 2 words** [*8 bytes* in 32-bit systems, *16 bytes* in 64-bit systems] from the beginning. However, when I dump first bytes from memory at the object location, first field's raw offset from the object's address is **only 1 32-bit word** (*4 bytes*), which doesn't make any sense for both types of systems. From the question I've linked:

```
class Program
{
    // Here is the function.
    // I suggest looking at the original question's solution, as it is 
    // more reliable.
    static IntPtr getPointerToObject(Object unmanagedObject)
    {
        GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(unmanagedObject, GCHandleType.WeakTrackResurrection);
        IntPtr thePointer = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(GCHandle.ToIntPtr(gcHandle));
        gcHandle.Free();
        return thePointer;
    }
    class TestClass
    {
        uint a = 0xDEADBEEF;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] cls = new byte[16];

        var test = new TestClass();

        var thePointer = getPointerToObject(test);
        Marshal.Copy(thePointer, cls, 0, 16); //Dump first 16 bytes...
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(thePointer.ToInt32())));
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(cls));

        Console.ReadLine();

        gcHandle.Free();
    }
}
/* Example output (yours should be different):
40-23-CA-02
4C-38-04-01-EF-BE-AD-DE-00-00-00-80-B4-21-50-73

That field's value is "EF-BE-AD-DE", 0xDEADBEEF as it is stored in memory. Yay, we found it!
*/
```

Why is so? Maybe I've just got the address wrong, but how and why? And if I didn't, what could be wrong anyway? Maybe, if that article is wrong, I simply misunderstood what managed class header looks like? Or maybe it doesn't have that Lock pointer - but why and how is this possible?..

(These are, obviously, only a few possible options, and, while I'm still going to carefully check each one I can predict, wild guessing cannot compare in both time and accuracy to a correct answer.)

Comment: The object pointer points to the 2nd field in the object header.  A neat trick to keep the machine code more compact, it is the one that's most likely to be used.  Do keep in mind that the code is drastically wrong, disaster strikes when the garbage collector runs after the getPtrToObject() call.  Low odds, not zero.  Pinning is a hard requirement.

Comment: @HansPassant Isn't the SyncRoot index supposed to be at offset -4?

Comment: Yes, the 1st field is thus at a negative index.

Comment: That would explain why you're only seeing an offset of only 4 bytes.

Comment: I assume other runtimes (Mono/DNX?) could _potentially_ have different implementations at this level, and it could also presumably change with any given release of the CLR too?  What I'm getting at is whether you can rely on such code working in all environments and into the future?

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you! That's exactly what I've been looking for! Could you please post this as the answer, so I could mark it as the accepted one?

About unsafety - you are absolutely right, I've explicitly stated this is a dangerous hack. But I really desperate for it.  How can I pin a class object?

Comment: I don't want to support an answer like that, it gets way too many people into trouble.  Beyond the pinning problem, other nasty issues are not having any idea how long the object is and how the fields are arranged.  There isn't any way to find out.  Use a debugger instead.

Comment: @JamesThorpe, yes, we totally cannot. Even if we do not take other version of CLR in account (which we do), this whole concept has a bunch of stability and safety problems already - working with the _managed_ objects in _unmanaged_ memory is already a bad idea, violating one of the main principles of the CLR itself, abstraction. But, like I said before, sometimes - in rare cases - it is necessary to peek behind the abstractions, and that's what the question is all about. I totally agree it is dangerous and unreliable, but sometimes this is *really* necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@HansPassant brilliantly pointed out that the pointer for the object in question points to the **second** structure, the method table. Now that totally makes sense for performance reasons, as the method table (RTTI structure) is used far more often than the SyncRoot structure, which, therefore, is still located right before it at the negative index -1.
He made it clear that he doesn't want to post this answer so I'm posting it myself, but the credit still goes to him.

But I would like to remind that this is a **dirty unreliable** hack, possibly making the system unstable:

> Beyond the pinning problem, other nasty issues are not having any idea how long the object is and how the fields are arranged.

You should use the debugger instead, unless you understand all the consequences, understand exactly what you are trying to do and *really* need to do it - using this, dirty and unreliable, way.